# Creating multiple keys inside javascript object with Array.map

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to accomplish is from an array, I want to map all of those values into one object. For example, if I have the following data below

```
const myKeys = ["prop_1", "prop_2", "prop_3"];
```

When I map over this array I would like to return an object with 3 properties from the array listed above. Something like this.

```
const myKeysObj = myKeys.map( key => {
// expected outcome {"prop_1" : "some_value", "prop_2": "some_value", "prop_3": "some_value"}
// actual outcome {key: "some_value"}
return {[key]: "some_value"}
})
```

What can I do to have all three of my props in my array to be properties for a each object returned?

Comment: The phrasing of your question is confusing. Do you want one object or three?

Comment: Three. It should be dependent on whatever I am mapping over. Since I am mapping over myKeys, I would expect three objects retuned because of the size of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to reduce the keys into an *object*, in which case `reduce` is more appropriate than `.map`:

```js
const myKeys = ["prop_1", "prop_2", "prop_3"];
const output = myKeys.reduce((a, key) => {
  a[key] = 'some_value';
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This works!! Thank you sir!! I will select this as the answer when it allows me.

Comment: `myKeys.reduce((a, key) => Object.assign(a, { [key]: 'some_value' }), {})`

Comment: @PeterTran Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)